# Trying to use VGG16 keras model for audio

Tags: python, audio, keras

I'm trying to use the vgg16 keras model for sound prediction.
I'm just changing the last layer for my prediction :

```
base_model = VGG16(include_top=False,
                  input_shape = (128,431,3),
                  weights = 'imagenet')

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(base_model)
        model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
        model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
        model.summary()
```

The shape of my data is :
`(128,431,1)`
(I obtained it with mel_spectrogram from librosa library)

but the Keras model needs `(128,431,3)`

I tried to use the stack method from numpy but the process stopped. I think this is because there is too much data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in using imagenet weights. It requires the number of channels to be 3. When creating the model, set weights to `None` and it should work.

```
import keras
base_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False,
                  input_shape = (128,431,1),
                  weights = None)
```